# PHP Email Form Not Submitting

Tags: php, html, forms, email, contacts

Okay, so I've looked all around for this specific question but I wasn't able to find it, so I hope this isn't a repeat.

So I have set up a contacts form using my "/contacts.html" page linked to "html_form_send.php" located on my local host. Once the user presses "submit" this message comes up on the next page:

"We are very sorry, but there were error(s) found with the form you submitted. These errors appear below.

We are sorry, but there appears to be a problem with the form you submitted.

Please go back and fix these errors."

This message appears whether you fill out all fields or none of the fields, correctly, or incorrectly. Why?

```
    <?php
if(isset($_POST['email'])) {

    // CHANGE THE TWO LINES BELOW
    $email_to = "xxxxxxxx.yyyyyyy@gmail.com";

    $email_subject = "Quantum1Connect Contact Request";


    function died($error) {
        // your error code can go here
        echo "We are very sorry, but there were error(s) found with the form you submitted. ";
        echo "These errors appear below.<br /><br />";
        echo $error."<br /><br />";
        echo "Please go back and fix these errors.<br /><br />";
        die();
    }

    // validation expected data exists
    if(!isset($_POST['first_name']) ||
        !isset($_POST['last_name']) ||
        !isset($_POST['email']) ||
        !isset($_POST['telephone']) ||
        !isset($_POST['comments'])) {
        died('We are sorry, but there appears to be a problem with the form you submitted.');       
    }

    $first_name = $_POST['first_name']; // required
    $last_name = $_POST['last_name']; // not required
    $email_from = $_POST['email']; // required
    $telephone = $_POST['telephone']; // not required
    $comments = $_POST['comments']; // required

    $error_message = "";
    $email_exp = '/^[A-Za-z0-9._%-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}$/';
  if(!preg_match($email_exp,$email_from)) {
    $error_message .= 'The Email Address you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
  }
    $string_exp = "/^[A-Za-z .'-]+$/";
  if(!preg_match($string_exp,$first_name)) {
    $error_message .= 'The First Name you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
  }
  if(!preg_match($string_exp,$last_name)) {
    $error_message .= 'The Last Name you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
  }
  if(strlen($comments) < 2) {
    $error_message .= 'The Comments you entered do not appear to be valid.<br />';
  }
  if(strlen($error_message) > 0) {
    died($error_message);
  }
    $email_message = "Form details below.\n\n";

    function clean_string($string) {
      $bad = array("content-type","bcc:","to:","cc:","href");
      return str_replace($bad,"",$string);
    }

    $email_message .= "First Name: ".clean_string($first_name)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Last Name: ".clean_string($last_name)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Email: ".clean_string($email_from)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Telephone: ".clean_string($telephone)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Comments: ".clean_string($comments)."\n";


// create email headers
$headers = 'From: '.$email_from."\r\n".
'Reply-To: '.$email_from."\r\n" .
'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers);  
?>

<!-- place your own success html below -->

Thanks for contacting me! I will respond within 24 hours of receiving your message!

<?php
}
die();
?>

     <div id="content">
        <div class="content_item">
          <h2>Contact Me!</h2>
          <p>Whether you have constructive criticism, advise, questions, or a request, this is the place to do it! </p>
          <form name="htmlform" method="post" action="http://localhost/html_form_send.php">
            <div style="width:170px; float:left;"><p><label for="first_name">First Name *</label></p></div>
              <div style="width:430px; float:right;"><p><input class="contact" type="text" name="first_name" value="" /></p></div>
            <div style="width:170px; float:left;"><p><label for="last_name">Last Name </label></p></div>
                <div style="width:430px; float:right;"><p><input class="contact" type="text" name="last_name" value="" /></p></div>
            <div style="width:170px; float:left;"><p><label for="email">Email Address * </label></p></div>
            <div style="width:430px; float:right;"><p><input class="contact" type="text" name="email" value="" /></p></div>
            <div style="width:170px; float:left;"><p><label for="telephone">Phone Number  </label></p></div>
            <div style="width:430px; float:right;"><p><input class="contact" type="text" name="phone" value="" /></p></div>
            <div style="width:170px; float:left;"><p><label for="comments">Message *</label></p></div>
              <div style="width:430px; float:right;"><p><textarea class="contact textarea" rows="8" cols="50" name="message"></textarea></p></div>
            <br style="clear:both;" />
            <p style="padding: 10px 0 10px 0;">Please enter the answer to this simple math question (to prevent spam)</p>
            <div style="width:170px; float:left;"><p>Maths Question: 9 + 3 = ?</p></div>
              <div style="width:430px; float:right;">
            <p><input type="text" name="user_answer" class="contact" /><input type="hidden" name="answer" value="4d76fe9775"/></p>
            </div>
            <div style="width:430px; float:right;">
            <p style="padding-top: 15px"><form action="index.php"><input type="submit" value="Submit"></p>
            </div>
          </form>
        </div><!--close content_item-->
```

Any help would be much appreciated, thank you so much!

Answer (score 4):

Change:

```
<textarea class="contact textarea" rows="8" cols="50" name="message"></textarea>
```

to:

```
<textarea class="contact textarea" rows="8" cols="50" name="comments"></textarea>
```

You have set the name of the html textarea to **message** but you are testing for a textarea named **comments** in your php code.

Also as @Fred-ii pointed out, you are testing for **telephone** in the POST, but the value in html is **phone**

**AND** Remove - `<form action="index.php">` that creates a SECOND form!

*BTW, it should take you just half the effort of posting this question in SO, to run some quick debug echo/print_r/error_reporting statements and figure this out. If you are planning to get into more programming in the future, I highly recommend you work on your debugging skills, it is way more easier and efficient for such small problems. For the bigger ones, there is always SO :-)*

Not being cynical, just an advice :) Best of luck!

Comment: Actually, you missed one.

Comment: @Fred-ii- missed one what?

Comment: Yepper +1 Plus, OP has two `<form` tags and only one `</form>` that could pose problems. Too many things wrong with OP's code.

Comment: @Fred-ii-*sigh* is there no end to this? :( Well I am done pointing out, (most of which are your's btw :-), I guess OP should just start helping himself, like I had noted in my answer...

Comment: Sometimes, no. But in this case, your answer has covered everything. I tested OP's code beforehand just to make sure, however the math equation check is useless lol OP isn't using it so I don't know why it's in there to start with. Let's hope OP doesn't come back and say "it doesn't work". That would be a server issue and not PHP's fault.

Comment: @Fred-ii- My initial thought when I saw the comment/message naming mismatch is that we all make such mistakes while working for too long, and a fresh pair of eyes help find it very fast. However I think the OP has copied over a existing form and missed quite a few areas while making changes to it...

Comment: True, a few pairs of eyes definitely help. However, it's really the OP's job to make sure everything matches. You/we are just here to outline where the errors were made. Many a time and if not 9 times out of 10, people don't bother or know about error checking/reporting and take it for granted that their code will ***magically work.*** - With that said, OP has enough to make it work, since your answer solves it. If it then doesn't work for the OP, OP probably doesn't have `mail()` / PHP installed and properly configured. **That's not our problem.** *Cheers*

Comment: P.s.: Even a missing dot/comma/semi-colon can ruin someone's day lol - it's happened to me (once), it's happened to others, it may strike again!

Comment: @Fred-ii-so true, which is why I always maintain that it is a crime to program in dev environments with error reporting turned off... I have actually met programmers who do not even know how to turn it on! I mean like people who do that for a living, not a hobbyist building a family site...